# Mounting network drives with Terminal in OSX 10.12 / Sierra

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, mount, macos-sierra

I just updated to OSX 10.12 / Sierra.
Usually when I reboot my computer, I run the following in a script to mount my network drives:

```
mount -t afp afp://user:password@10.1.1.10/SKYDEDAGE /Volumes/SKYDEDAGE2015
```

This has always worked. However after updating to OSX 10.12 / Sierra, this command no longer works. In the script I run, Prior to using the mount command, I make a directory/mountpoint in 'Volumes'. The command still doesn't work, even though the directory/mountpoint exists.

I get this error code:

```
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 1, errno is 1
```

Any ideas why this aren't working anymore?

Comment: Anyone? I can't possibly be the only one with this problem :-/

Comment: Which user is running the script? Are you sure that this user has a permission to write in `/Volumes` and/or in `/Volumes/SKYDEDAGE2015`? Usually `error 1` means you have insufficient permissions.

Comment: Thanks, alexK!!

I tried mounting using sudo, and that worked. Now I'll have it all up'n'runnin' again...

Comment: Hmmm, looks like I was too quick...
Now I don't get an error message, and the volumes seems to mount. They show up in the sidebar of a Finder window, like they're supposed to do.

However, when I try to access them, I get a 'Connection failed' message in Finder....

Comment: If you do `sudo ls` against the volume - would you be able to see the content? If yes - try doing `ls` with a regular user. Probably your user just doesn't have a permission to read or execute on the volume folder.

Comment: Possibly related to the permissions changes for /Volumes under Sierra? See https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2016/09/21/macos-sierras-volumes-folder-is-no-longer-world-writable/

Answer (score 11):

Just in case anyone else stumbles over this question and needs a solution, in OS X 10.12, you can use "open":

```
open smb://<user>:<password>@server/<Volume>
```

The extra step with creating the folder in /Volumes can be omitted

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
mount -t smbfs //user@10.1.1.10/SKYDEDAGE   /Volumes/SKYDEDAGE2015
```

I prefer to enter passwords manually

macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Did you need to create a /Volumes/SKYDEDAGE2015 manually?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because around Sierra, Apple changed /Volumes so that it was no longer globally readable or writeable.

You have to create a mount folder with sudo, and mount with sudo:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Volumes/mount && sudo mount -t AFP afp://user:pass@redlantern.apple.com/mount /Volumes/mount
```

You can also use:

```
open smb://<user>:<password>@server/<Volume>
```

But that will prompt the user, so won't work in in a startup script.